# Using npm run script with JS hint on Windows to delint all subdirectories

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, windows, jshint

I have a node.js app and jshint installed globally in Windows 7. I'm trying to configure the start script so that I can view any potential errors while the tasks are loading.

Here's my project directory:

```
app
--routes.js
config
--config.js
--sequelize.js
--passport.js
views
--index.ejs
package.json
.gitignore
.jshintrc
```

From the top level of the directory, when I run jshint ., to do error detection recursively on all subfolders, I get the output as expected. However, when I try to establish a script within package.json like so:

```
"scripts": {
   "start": "npm run nodemon ./app.js",
   "lint": "jshint .",
   "nodemon": "nodemon"
},
"devDependencies": {
   "jshint": "^2.9.2"
}
```

and I confirm that the "lint" script is registered as such:

```
npm run
Lifecycle scripts included in chinese-democracy:
start
npm run nodemon ./app.js

available via `npm run-script`:
lint
    jshint .
nodemon
    nodemon
```

and then try

```
npm run lint
```

I get the same output of errors as before with the following information:

[image]

Here is my complete package.json file for reference:

```
{
   "name": "chinese-democracy",
   "dependencies": {
      "body-parser": "^1.15.2",
      "config": "^1.21.0",
      "connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
      "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
      "crypto": "0.0.3",
      "ejs": "^2.4.2",
      "express": "4.14.0",
      "express-session": "^1.14.0",
      "lodash": "^4.13.1",
      "mysql": "^2.11.1",
      "nodemon": "^1.10.0",
      "passport": "^0.3.2",
      "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
      "path": "^0.12.7",
      "sequelize": "^3.23.4"
    },
    "scripts": {
      "start": "npm run nodemon ./app.js",
      "lint": "jshint .",
      "nodemon": "nodemon"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "jshint": "^2.9.2"
    }
}
```

In essence, why did the jshint output generate but the error message was raised saying it failed?

Comment: Perhaps - https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/6124 - In short - "jshint . || true". Seems hacky though;

Comment: Just tried "lint": "jshint . || true" and the exact same thing occurred with the additional prompt that: 'true' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: The `|| true` trick does not work on Windows. If you only need it to work on Windows, you can probably do something like `|| rem` or `|| call` or some other Windows command that is relatively harmless. If you want it to work on both Windows and UNIX-like operating systems, you might be able to somehow use [cash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cash) as a devDependency to make `true` available on Windows? Not exactly sure how that would work and I don't have a Windows machine handy to experiment, but I'd start at https://www.npmjs.com/package/cash#wow-but-i-want-this-programmatically.